# Magento script getstore()->SetId()

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working on a script, I have this code:

`Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(20);
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()`

everything is working but I don't understand what
 *Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(20)*
does exactly and why if I delete it the script doesn't work anymore?

Comment: I guess the script would still work with just `Mage::app()` which initializes Magento with the default store. But without knowing the rest of your script this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

***setId()*** sets the store id as 20 to the ***current store object***

And your order collection code filters & fetches data based on the current store id. You probably did not initialize Magento with a store in your custom script.